# Selecting longest string from each value of table column

Tags: r, stringr, data-wrangling

I have the following date frame:

| ID TX | GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| HUDJDUDOOD--BANNK2--OLDODOLD985555545UIJF | 1 |
| UJDID YUH23498 IDX09 | 2 |
| 854 UIJSAZXC | 3 |

I would like to be able to extract the longest string for each value under the column `ID TX` knowing that each cell may have different strings or maybe just one but in some instances they may be separated by punctuation such as `"," "--", "," "--"` etc or even a space `" ".`

I have thought of the following I need to first replace punctuation  by a white space `" "` then.. separate or split each cell by `" "` after that I will calculate the length of each string perhaps with `nchart()` or `str_length()` and select the index of the string the the longest value, but I have not been able yet to do so as I cant manage to select the index (word) that I need after splitting the values since I don't know in what index the longest string may be.. my desired output would be:

| OUTPUT |
| --- |
| OLDODOLD985555545UIJF |
| YUH23498 |
| UIJSAZXC |

Side note: no worries there will not be ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Your data
dat <- structure(list(ID_TX = c("HUDJDUDOOD--BANNK2--OLDODOLD985555545UIJF", 
"UJDID YUH23498 IDX09", "854 UIJSAZXC"), GROUP = 1:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

# Splitting strings in the data
spl <- strsplit(dat$ID_TX, "--|\\s")

# Identify the position of the longest string in each row
idx <- spl|> lapply(nchar) |> lapply(which.max) |> unlist()

# Select the longest string and bind them to a data.frame
mapply(function(x,y) spl[[x]][y], seq_along(idx),idx) |>
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames("OUTPUT")

# The result

#                 OUTPUT
#1 OLDODOLD985555545UIJF
#2              YUH23498
#3              UIJSAZXC
```